# Moving from JSFiddle to Actual Usable Code

Tags: jsfiddle

I found a very helpful website called jsfiddle.net, and I was playing around with it to understand how different pieces of code work.  In particular, I found [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/dakra/U3pVM/):

HTML

```
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Todo</h2>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <span>{{remaining()}} of {{todos.length}} remaining</span>
    [ <a href="" ng-click="archive()">archive</a> ]
    <ul class="unstyled">
      <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
        <span class="done-{{todo.done}}">{{todo.text}}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form ng-submit="addTodo()">
      <input type="text" ng-model="todoText"  size="30"
             placeholder="add new todo here">
      <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="add">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.done-true {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: grey;
}
```

Javascript

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.todos = [
    {text:'learn angular', done:true},
    {text:'build an angular app', done:false}];

  $scope.addTodo = function() {
    $scope.todos.push({text:$scope.todoText, done:false});
    $scope.todoText = '';
  };

  $scope.remaining = function() {
    var count = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.todos, function(todo) {
      count += todo.done ? 0 : 1;
    });
    return count;
  };

  $scope.archive = function() {
    var oldTodos = $scope.todos;
    $scope.todos = [];
    angular.forEach(oldTodos, function(todo) {
      if (!todo.done) $scope.todos.push(todo);
    });
  };
}
```

One thing that confused me though is that it splits up CSS, HTML, and JavaScript.  It was my understanding that these were components that all worked together in one block of code rather than in separate files.  Are there actually development environments that present code as JSFiddle does?  Is it just for instructional purposes and nothing else?  Thanks.

Comment: Pretty much **every** development environment keeps separate things in separate files.

Comment: Breaking separate things into separate files is proper. If you keep all of the style information in a separate .css file for instance, and include that .css file in your HTML, then changing your style for everything means making a single change to the .css file, and the change will have an effect on every HTML file that included it. Keeping it all together means you have to edit every single HTML file to make the same change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it was my understanding that these were components that all worked
>   together in one block of code rather than in separate files.

If you are going to re-use Javascript and styles, then they are best broken out into separate files so you do not have to re-write the same code more than once.

I always think it is best practice to separate html, css, and js into separate files and include them into your HTML as needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `/show` to the end of a JSFiddle URL to get a standalone page that has all the code combined.

[Here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/dakra/U3pVM/show/light/) it is with your code

JSFiddle separated them because it makes it much easier to divide your code. I.e. all your CSS goes into the CSS section.

You could always put the Javascript and CSS in their own files and add them to the HTML page but it does not make any difference.